# How to generate a 'HTML select' from XSD definition

Tags: xsd

I try to generate HTML code from XSD and plan to generate a selection with defined values.
I could use a restriction in XSD but I need the values of the options too.

```
<select name="Pizza" size="5">
      <option value="P101">Pizza Napoli</option>
      <option value="P102">Pizza Funghi</option>
</select>
```

What would be the proper XSD to define a HTML select with options and values?

Answer (score 0):

A standard `xs:restriction` will allow you to mark up the values, but for the descriptions I'd just use a custom namespace on top of the schema. Something like this would do it:

```
 <xs:element name="Pizza" xmlns:pizza="http://my.custom.namespace/pizza">
   <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:enumeration value="P101" pizza:description="Pizza Napoli"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="P102" pizza:description="Pizza Funghi"/>
     </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:element>
```

XML is extensible and so therefore is XML schema.

This approach has the benefit that you can still validate data against the schema easily (a validator will simply ignore the custom namespace), but when converting to HTML, you can write out the options in the way you want.